# no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

Sorry for novice question, i am a beginner in `JSON`.

I have the following json:

```
{
   "destination_addresses" : [ "San Francisco, Californie, États-Unis", "Victoria, BC, Canada" ],
   "origin_addresses" : [ "Vancouver, BC, Canada", "Seattle, Washington, États-Unis" ],
   "rows" : [
      {
         "elements" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "1 707 km",
                  "value" : 1707145
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "3 jours 19 heures",
                  "value" : 327471
               },
               "status" : "OK"
            },
           ]
      },

   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

and i am going to get `duration` value. 
i used this line

`duration = json["rows"][0]["elements"]["duration"]["text"]`

but i am facing with this erorr

```
 no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the example JSON, `elements` is an array:

```
"elements" : [...
```

so needs to be indexed numerically e.g.

```
duration = json["rows"][0]["elements"][0]["duration"]["text"]
```

currently the string `"duration"` is being used to index into the `elements` array leading to the error you're seeing.